# How to write Criteria in my case

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have an class called PatientCase which maps to PatientCase table in the Database.
I have another class called Provider which maps to Provider table in the Database.
PatientCase class has 2 classes as Properties
   1) AssignedProvider of type Provider   -- Maps to AssignedProviderID in PatientCaseTable
   2) AncillaryProvider of type Provider  -- Maps to AncillaryProviderID in PatientCaseTable

NOW,
Given a ProviderID, how can i filter case objects such that

```
 AssignedProviderID = ProviderID  
                  OR  
    AncillaryProviderID = ProviderID
```

Plz Help me

Comment: Why do you need Criteria for this? Does it need to be dynamic? Static queries are much simpler in HQL.

Answer (score 1):

The long way of classic Criteria is the following:

```
session
  .CreateCriteria<PatientCase>()
  .Add(new Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("AssignedProvider", provider))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("AncillaryProvider", provider)));
```

not that I'm using the provider itself as argument, not its Id. It is generally more "object oriented" to work with entities instead with id. To use the ids, you may join the tables:

```
session
  .CreateCriteria<PatientCase>()
  .CreateCriteria("AssignedProvider", "assigned")
  .CreateCriteria("AncillaryProvider", "ancillary")
  .Add(new Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("assigned.Id", providerId))
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ancillary", providerId)));
```

There are easier and more readable syntaxes around, at least in NH 3.0 (eg. QueryOver).

It is also easier to do this with HQL:

```
session
  .CreateQuery(
    @"select case from PatientCase case
    where case.AssignedProvider = :provider
      or case.AncillaryProvider = :provider")
  .SetEntity("provider", provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks stefan,
Through your answer I have learnt more about criteria.
Anyways,
Here is how I have solved the problem

```
caseCriteria.Add(
    Expression.Or(
        Expression.Eq("Provider.Providerid", providerId),
        Expression.Eq("AncillaryProvider.Providerid", providerId)
   )
);
```